# ¿Como aplicar un 'identificador incrementable' para cada instancia de clase?

Tags: java

**Problema:**

Poniendo todo en contexto y de manera simple, dispongo de una clase de la cual deseo obtener via `toString()` exclusivamente su identificador que lo establezco como un valor del tipo `int`.

```
public class Packet {
  //private static int ID=2048;
  private static int ID=0;
  
  public Packet() {
    ID++;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Packet batch sender ID: "+ID;
  }
}
```

Mi clase `Packet` va a instanciarse indeterminadamente durante todo el ciclo de ejecución de la aplicación; suponiendo un numero concreto de instancias: 5.

**Resultados Actuales:**

```
Packet batch sender ID: 5
Packet batch sender ID: 5
Packet batch sender ID: 5
Packet batch sender ID: 5
Packet batch sender ID: 5
```

**Resultados Esperados:**

```
Packet batch sender ID: 1
Packet batch sender ID: 2
Packet batch sender ID: 3
Packet batch sender ID: 4
Packet batch sender ID: 5
```

**Lo que he intentado como solución alternativa:**

Cambiar y/o sobrecargar el constructor y pasar el identificador desde afuera de la clase, pero es exactamente eso lo que busco evitar por una cuestión de flexibilidad en la estructura del programa, no quisiera estar modificando cualquier numero de clases que usen `Packet` solo para pasar un simple valor...

```
public class Packet {
  private int ID=0;
  public Packet(int ID) {
    this.ID=ID;
  }

  public Packet() {}

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Packet batch sender ID: "+ID;
  }
}
```

Esto funciona pero quisiera que sea la misma clase quien sea capaz de generar su propio numero de instancia.

¿De que manera puedo lograr ese comportamiento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pero... lo resolviste en el primer intento...

Tenes que tener 2 variables.. una estatica.. y otra privada a la clase...

```
public class Packet {

    private static int ID=0;

    private int PrivateID;
  
    public Packet() {
        ID++;
        PrivateId = ID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Packet batch sender ID: "+ PrivateID;
    }
}
```

De esa forma, al entrar, usas la global para asignar a la propia de la clase el valor que estas buscando.

Comment: +1 y gracias @gbianchi Entonces me faltaba una variable mas!! para no obtener el total de la cuenta de golpe para cada instancia. Resuelto.